# Should a cookie header be set on every response?

Tags: python, http, session, pyramid

Let's say you're implementing sessions.

You check whether the browser presents a session cookie. If yes, you authenticate the cookie and find the user that the session is associated with, and move on processing the request.

If you don't find a session cookie, you create a new session and send a cookie to the browser whch you expect to receive on subsequent requests.

Now my question is: if you did find a session cookie in a request, would you **resend** the same cookie in the response. Under what circumstances is this right?

Note: I ask this as a Pyramid (Python) programmer, because Pyramid implementation sends the session cookie unconditionally on every response. ([go to code](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/session.py))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, you don't need to set the cookie on each and every response. The browser already has the cookie and will continue sending it to the server as long as it is still valid.

Specifically, a Pyramid session cookie is set on every request because it contains a signed and timestamped secret that can expire separately from the normal cookie expiration mechanisms. By setting a *new* cookie each time Pyramid gets to update the embedded timestamp to show the session is still fresh. In other words, the cookie set is a different one each time.

Comment: Yes, you're right! The default session implementation in Pyramid stores access time in the cookie -- which it needs to update on every request, hence resetting the cookie on every response. And, alternate implementations like [pyramid_beaker](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_beaker/blob/master/pyramid_beaker/__init__.py) and [pyramid_redis_sessions](https://github.com/ericrasmussen/pyramid_redis_sessions/blob/master/pyramid_redis_sessions/__init__.py) don't do it unconditionally. You're right.

Answer (score 8):

For a *session* cookie (as in, a browser session cookie, that the client will destroy as soon as it is closed) I would probably not do this. It doesn't achieve anything in particular and it's a waste of bandwidth (albeit a small amount) to keep repeating yourself like this.

> > Here have a cookie.
>     < Thanks!
>     > No really, have a cookie.
>     < Isn't that the same cookie?
>     > Seriously, have this cookie.
>     < Stop it please.

It only makes sense to send the cookie again when you are changing something about it. So for a cookie with an absolute expiry time, you may want to renew that expiry time every so often. Obviously if you are changing the value stored in the cookie, you will also send the header again.

I am generally a PHP developer, and PHP native sessions do this (send it every time unconditionally) as well. I imagine the reasons for this are a) it's easier to implement and b) it attempts to account for user agents that are not behaving as they should, possibly ignoring expiry times or failing to write cookies to client side persistent storage or <insert other odd behaviour here>.

If everyone implements 2109/2965 properly, there is absolutely no reason for setting semantically identical cookies more than once. But wouldn't a developer's life be dull if people actually read standards?

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is a browser.
In distributed systems you for example you may login from one node and access the service from other nodes using the same session (if you have a thousand of nodes you would not want to login from each one)
Now let's say one of the nodes noticed that the cookie is about to expire, and it renews the cookie. The other nodes would not know about the change and would either renew the cookie again or use the old one. In either case your whole system would stop working, unless you do some elaborate internode messaging.
You could implement something like JWToken for that case but that has its own shortcomings ( for example not being able to logout) so it is not always acceptable. And besides the browsers do not understand jwtokens.